# How To Make An Image Change When Pressing A Specific Key In TKinter In Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python and was wondering how I could make an image change to another when a key is pressed.  I want my image to change from GuyUp.gif to GuyDown.gif when I press the down arrow key so it looks like my guy is actually walking normally.  My code in Python looks like this:

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
tk.title("Triangle Movement")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()
guyup = PhotoImage(file = 'GuyUp.gif')
canvas.create_image(5, 5, image = guyup, anchor = NW)
def movetriangle(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        canvas.move(1, 0, -4)
    elif event.keysym == 'Down':
        canvas.move(1, 0, 4)
    elif event.keysym == 'Left':
        canvas.move(1, -4, 0)
    elif event.keysym == 'Right':
        canvas.move(1, 4, 0)
    elif event.keysym == 'w':
        canvas.move(2, 0, -4)
    elif event.keysym == 's':
        canvas.move(2, 0, 4)
    elif event.keysym == 'a':
        canvas.move(2, -4, 0)
    else:
        canvas.move(2, 4, 0)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Up>', movetriangle)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Down>', movetriangle)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', movetriangle)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', movetriangle)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-w>', movetriangle)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-s>', movetriangle)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-a>', movetriangle)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-d>', movetriangle)
```

I do have the two images and would like to put it in my elif statement with the keysym of 'Down'
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Since you're new to Python, an indoctrination comment: read [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Your violation in this case was putting spaces around keyword arguments ;)

Answer (score 1):

First a comment: you're already binding all the keypresses differently, so why use all the conditionals in the callback? Just define separate `moveup`, `movedown`, etc. functions and bind them to the appropriate key press.

Now, for your image switching you'll need state in your application to know which image is displayed and which one isn't. Since you're using global variables and no classes, you'll have to store this information in global variables as well. Change the following part of your code:

```
current_image = PhotoImage(file='GuyUp.gif')
image_id = canvas.create_image(5, 5, image=current_image, anchor=NW)
other_image = PhotoImage(file='GuyDown.gif')
```

and add the following function

```
def swap_images():
    global current_image, other_image, image_id
    x, y = canvas.coords(image_id)
    canvas.delete(image_id)
    image_id = canvas.create_image(x, y, image=other_image)
    current_image, other_image = other_image, current_image
```

You can now place this function wherever you like in your program's logic.

You would probably be better off packaging all of what you've written in a class and using an instance variables instead of globals, and adapting the function to this case is left as an exercise ;)

---

**Edit**: Fixed the missing keyword in in the `create_image` method.

I've also realized you'll have to change your `canvas.move` calls to use `image_id` instead of `1` as the identifier. Perhaps a better alternative to storing it would be to use a tag on the object itself.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I am still having problems with it and the image will not change when pressing the down arrow key.  Should you change the image in the image_id to other_image instead of current_image?

Comment: Sorry! I'd missed an `image=` in the call. See the edit notes

Comment: Thank you for that!  I am going to keep practicing Python and hopefully create a simple game. :)

Comment: Oh my the code is still not working!  Do you have any idea what might be happening?  Sorry! :(

Comment: Not sure. [this](http://pastebin.com/YXNnmJJj) works for me. What exactly is failing?